# Step into: Stepping over non-user code : What is the meaning of this message?

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the meaning of the message below and how do you get rid of it?
This is with a C# WPF app using .NET 6.
The message appears in the Output window after running the the app.

Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'WpfApp1.App..ctor'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'WpfApp1.App.InitializeComponent'

Tried a search but did not find any answers.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this refers to 3rd party code. For example, code in the .NET Framework or .NET Core assemblies.

If you do not select this option, you will sometimes be able to step into the disassembled .NET source code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the messages by right-clicking on the Output window, then unchecking "Step Filtering Messages"